# How can I add smooth(or any transition) to my anchor scroll, using fragment, in an Angular App?

Tags: angular

so after a lot of searching, using fragment worked in implementing the anchor scroll in the page, but there is no smooth transition between it, is there any way I can add it? I'd really appreciate any help in this, thanks!

```
  <div class="row no-gutters ">
                  <div class="numerals one" [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="sec_one">
                    <a href="#sec_one"><span>01</span></a>
                  </div>
    </div>

<div id="sec_one">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum itaque voluptate aspernatur hic saepe quis voluptatum possimus omnis obcaecati eos.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular providing angular annimation, which helps to animate components by # tags and predefined methods. sine you working in angular 2+ application utilize angular animation

check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dmalexgjqom) example